# How to run or where to find the exact queries docs for docker monitoring in prometheus

Tags: docker, monitoring, grafana, prometheus, cadvisor

I am not able to figure out  the exact queries to run in **prometheus** for my requirements.

This is what I have done so far:

**Running a docker container with follwing properly setup**

1. setup **prometheus**
2. added **node-exporter** (has 2 nodes one local and another node-exporter running in another instance )
3. Added **cadvisor** for container metrics
4. Setup **graphana** with data -source as prometheus.
5. All the targets are up and healthy

> These are what I want to accomplish next

1. Count number of instance running as I have the node-exporter running on 2 instance it should be 2 ofcourse
2. Count and display the number  of running containers on each nodes
3. CPU utilization by the containers on the each nodes
4. Similarly memory utilization by the containers on each nodes

***TRIED SOLUTIONS:***

Imported the already build dashboard which has the queries being setup already. The container graph is showing **N/A**

It has the following queries written 
***count(rate(container_last_seen{name=~".+"}[$interval]))***

what is the problem with it.

Comment: Did you check Prometheus [DOC](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/)?

Comment: This [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-query-prometheus-on-ubuntu-14-04-part-1#step-2-%E2%80%94-installing-the-demo-instances) was a good tutorial for me to learn Prometheus query.

Comment: Here is the best solutions i found importing  the dashboard json file which has the query required. The container monitoring was not working because the cadvisor though was running on port 8080 which was also used by jenkins. i wonder why the cadvisor was still running when the port was used by another service. Not able to change the ports from the docker-compose though specifying new ports using the defauly  8080

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of docker containers I use:

```
count(rate(container_last_seen{id=~"/docker/.*",instance=~"localhost:.*"}[5m]))
```